# How do I make Text() wrap in SwiftUI when it is too long for the width of the device?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following and would like the longer text to wrap

```
Text("Long label that needs to be able to wrap but isn't doing it yet.")
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .lineLimit(0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58335789/359532

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out you can pass `nil` to the `.lineLimit` and it will make the `Text()` wrap as desired.

```
Text("Long label that needs to be able to wrap but isn't doing it yet.")
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .lineLimit(nil)
```

Comment: I am using a `Text` instance inside of a `NavigationButton` instance. I am not seeing `Text` instances wrap as of β2 when used inside of such containers. Have you also seen this behavior?

Comment: I haven't used that setup yet @NickKohrn

Answer (score 8):

Both `.fixedSize` and `.lineLimit(nil)` should work.

```
 Text("Label text")
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

OR

```
 Text("Label text")
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .lineLimit(nil)
```

`.fixedSize` is the preferred/suggested option from Apple to word wrap the text into next line

Comment: `.lineLimit(nil)` doesn't solve the problem on iOS 17, but the first solution works:

`Text("Label text").multilineTextAlignment(.leading).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this on the lastest XCode 11 beta, beta 7. I needed to specify a non-nil line limit and also use the `padding` modifier in order to achieve multiline text

```
Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.")
   .font(.subheadline)
   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
   .lineLimit(3)
   .padding()
```