# Adding unlimited lines in a Text (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Just figuring out how I can achieve multiple lines of text in a `Text`. It seems like the `Text` has the same default as `UILabel` (one line), but I can't find any function which meets this criteria.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            HStack {
                Text("Avocado Toast").font(.system(size: 24))
            }
            // This Text does cut, and I wonder how I can achieve multiple rows
            Text("Ingredients: Avocado, Almond Butter, Bread")
                .font(.system(size: 20))

        }
    }
}
```

#### Edit

`.lineLimit(X)`, did the trick. But is it possible to not set a specific amount, for instance. With just a 0?

Comment: try \n to go next line

Comment: Tried it out, but it just cuts with three dots @canister_exister

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478602/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56470402/1187415

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way that I can limit the text to 2 / 3 lines using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475779/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-limit-the-text-to-2-3-lines-using-swiftui)

Comment: @MartinR worked as a charm! Tried it out with 0 lines to adjust unlimited rows, but it seems like we have to set a specified amount of lines now

Comment: You can try Text("Something").truncationMode

Answer (score 174, accepted):

For wrapping Text in a Form `.lineLimit(Int.max)` did not work for me. It seems there needs to be some width for it to know when to wrap. I believe the official way is with `.fixedSize`:

```
Text(message)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

The documentation states:

> This example shows the effect of fixedSize(horizontal:vertical:) on a text view that is wider than its parent, preserving the ideal, untruncated width of the text view.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize(horizontal:vertical:)

Comment: Same thing happened to me. `horizontal: true, vertical: false` if you want your Text to expand vertically, `horizontal: false, vertical: true` to expand horizontally.

Comment: This should be the answer, ```.lineLimit``` is not working correctly at now.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the child sizing of the label is incorrect? Like somewhere Text()'s frame hasn't been set right?

Comment: @Zorayr Google "SwiftUI Layout System" for more info, but my understanding of SwiftUI is that the view determines its own size. There is nothing default in Text that determines the width other than the width of the total characters in the string. As the docs I included states, the fixedSize modifier will cause the Text view to use the parents width in determining its own width, which in turn will determine the height.

Comment: Note: There is a bug in iOS 17.0 Beta 8 that is messing up ScrollViews and unlimited line Text's. I thought it was related to the Text element I have having unlimited lines but I can't reproduce the bug in iOS 16.4 or iOS 16.0 so I hope it'll be fixed by Apple before 17.0 is fully released to public

Comment: When I use this approach inside a popover, the popover's size doesn't adjust to the wrapped Text, so the top and bottom of the text becoming hidden outside the bounds of the popover. Would be great if someone could explain how to fix! (Maybe I'll try just adding more padding.)

Answer (score 33):

Use `.lineLimit()` to limit the amount of lines of text. It takes an optional Int (`Int?`) as an argument, and `.lineLimit(nil)` allows unlimited lines.

**Edit**: As of SwiftUI Beta 5, `Text` has a default line limit of `nil`, so text in `Text` will wrap by default.

Comment: In case where `lineLimit(nil)` does not work, specify a number, like `lineLimit(100)`

Comment: `lineLimit` does not work, use `fixedSize` as Michael suggested

Answer (score 7):

I had to add 2 different modifiers for it to work:

```
Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pharetra neque ex, at consectetur leo semper eu. Ut finibus maximus ex et maximus. Proin vel sagittis sapien, sed tincidunt orci.")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

If you don't add the `frame`, it will have your text out of the bounds of the screen, and `fixedSize` allows it to have multiple lines visible

Answer (score 5):

```
Text("Professional Burnout and how to overcome it")
     .font(.callout)
     .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
     .frame(width: 220)
```

[image: text wrap to next line]

Comment: Works for me trying to put label under textfield

Answer (score 3):

My text kept truncating even with no line limit applied. Wrapping my content in a `ScrollView {}` solved it.

See more info here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-using-scrollview

Comment: Yes it seems otherwise the view prioritizes fitting the Text into the view

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous answers worked for me, but `.lineLimit(Int.max)` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`lineLimit` and `fixedSize` work together.

Setting `.fixedSize` with `(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` will allow the Text to grow.

Setting `lineLimit` determines up to how many lines the Text will grow to

- a nil value is no limit

  - `lineLimit(nil)` doesn't seem to be necessary in conjunction with `.fixedSize` as `.fixedSize` alone will allow the label to grow as far as it can.

Example:

```swift
Text("Using `___VARIABLE_\(identifier): identifier___` in your template will replace that macro with `\(defaultValue)`")
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    .lineLimit(2)
```

[image: lineLimit(2)]

`lineLimit(1)`

[image: lineLimit(1)]

Answer (score 1):

If lineLimit(nil) is not working for you, try setting layoutPriority manually to whatever it suits you `.layoutPriority(0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me. Use `lineLimit` with `multilineTextAlignment`

```
Text("")
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .lineLimit(2)
```